# How to update nested field in a DynamoDB item when one of its parent fields may not exist

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Say I have several items that need to be updated in dynamodb like so:

```json
{
  "PK": "THING",
  "SK": "ZERO",
}
```

```json
{
  "PK": "THING",
  "SK": "ONE",
  "one": { }
}
```

```json
{
  "PK": "THING",
  "SK": "TWO",
  "one": { 
    "two": {}
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "PK": "THING",
  "SK": "THREE",
  "one": {
    "two": {
      "three": {
        "a": "hello",
        "b": "goodbye"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How could I update all of these items so `one.two.three.a == "world"`.

In some cases `one` may not exist. In others, `one.two` may not exist, and so on. There is no guarantee that `one.two.three.a` exists in the item prior to the update query.

There could be 1000s of items like this that all need to be updated so ideally there would be an efficient way of doing this.

It doesn't have to be transactional so updates can be done individually to each item.

I have tried several things including:

```js
const UpdateExpression = "SET #one = if_not_exists(#one, :one), #one.#two = if_not_exists(#one.#two, :two), #one.#two.#three = if_not_exists(#one.#two.#three, :three), #one.#two.#three.#a = :a"

const ExpressionAttributeNames = {
  "#one": "one",
  "#two": "two",
  "#three": "three",
  "#a": "a"
}

const ExpressionAttributeValues = {
  ":one": {
    "two": {
      "three": {
        "a": "world"
      }
    }
  },
  ":two": {
    "three": {
      "a": "world"
    }
  },
  ":three": {
    "a": "world"
  },
  ":a": "world"
}
```

But I get the error: `Invalid UpdateExpression: Two document paths overlap with each other; must remove or rewrite one of these paths`.

or something like:

```js
const UpdateExpression = "SET #one.#two.#three.#a = :a";

const ExpressionAttributeNames = {
  "#one": "one",
  "#two": "two",
  "#three": "three",
  "#a": "a"
}

const ExpressionAttributeValues = {
  ":a": "world"
}
```

And I get the error: `The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update`.

There are answers to some related questions that suggest catching the failed update request and then adding the missing field in, but my understanding is that this would only work for a case where there is only one parent field that is missing so I don't believe this approach can be used.

What would the update expression, expression attribute names, expression attribute values, conditional expression, etc.. look like to solve this problem?

(My preference is Typescript, but happy to have examples of any other language)